# image Borders are not visible in outlook even i tried a div around it

Tags: html

this is my code please help me around im working on mail chimp

```html
<tr>
  <td style="font-family:Georgia, Times, serif;font-weight:normal;color:#959595;padding-bottom:20px;padding-top:3px;padding-left:20px;line-height:20px;padding-right:24px;" bgcolor="#ffffff">
    <p align="center">
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sjyU4EMsjzo&amp;t=3s" target="">
        <div style="border:3px solid #000000;"><img border-color="#000000" style="BORDER-TOP:  black 3px solid;color:#959595; HEIGHT: 175px; BORDER-RIGHT: black 3px solid; WIDTH: 288px; BORDER-BOTTOM: black 3px solid; BORDER-LEFT: black 3px solid" border="3" hspace="0" alt="" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/9dd806f6696c31d8fe4e2409d/images/a22921ab-2337-4b3c-8c7e-1c7c2633c13c.jpg"
            width="288" height="175"></div>
      </a>
      <font color="#959595" size="6">

        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WMlq9AqFYdA" target="">
          <div style="border:3px solid #000000;"><img border-color="#000000" style="BORDER-TOP: black 3px solid;  HEIGHT: 177px; BORDER-RIGHT: black 3px solid; WIDTH: 283px; BORDER-BOTTOM: black 3px solid; BORDER-LEFT: black 3px solid" border="3" hspace="0" alt="" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/9dd806f6696c31d8fe4e2409d/images/091d16c0-1b98-47e5-bb3e-c7ebc38b3d2c.jpg"
              width="283" height="177"></div>
        </a>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="font-size:15px;font-family:Calibri, Candara, Segoe, Optima, Arial, sans-serif;text-align:justify;" align="center">Just take a look at How it Works video below and see for yourself how easy and simple it really is. And see what some of our Service Providers have to say about Fixonclick and how it's helped them
    </p>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: explain more detail...?

Comment: actually, I'm designing an email for my campaign in mailchimp whenever I sent a test email to my gmail the image borders are visible perfectly but when I sent the same email to my outlook the image border are not visible above is my code I just need to find out how to show borders in outlook. outlook version 2010

Answer (score 0):

Outlook prefers to ignore CSS, no idea why but it is most likely that you need to define a width for your `<td>`.

> I don't know the code your image is nested in, but sometimes borders
>   are not displayed, because elements around take away the space for it.
>   Outlook 2007/10/13 likes defined width per  - otherwise it
>   interprets the width its own way.
>
> *Source:
>   https://litmus.com/community/discussions/143-margins-and-borders-in-outlook*

Comment: but I didn't get the proper solution all the other CSS is working but only the image borders are not visible in outlook